# Linq query to search

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a collection of Employee class and employee class has few properties like departement,manager name,payscale,designation etc.Now in my webapi, i have a search method in which i am searching a string across all fields of webapi

like if I search **Peter** it'll search in all fields(departement,manager_name,payscale,designation) of all employees.For this i am using below:-

```
    public IEnumerable<Employee> Search(string searchstr)
    {
        if (repository != null)
        {
            var query =
                from employees in repository.GetEmployees()
                where
                    (employees.departement != null && employees.departement.Contains(searchstr)) ||
                    (employees.payscale != null && employees.payscale.Contains(searchstr))
                    (movie.designation != null && movie.designation.Contains(searchstr)) )
                select employees;

            return query.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(c => c.employeeid);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }
    }
```

Though i am getting desired result,i have not to use that query.Is there any other way to rewrite same query?

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by Noctis, using reflection results in a heavy task for the .NET runtime.

Here is some example code that loops trough all properties of a class and searchs a string concidence. It uses reflection ;)

Any questions, leave a comment asking!

The code in the entry point of the APP:

```
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var person1 = new Person {Name = "The first name", Address = "The first address"};
        var person2 = new Person {Name = "The second name", Address = "The second address"};

        var results = SearchStringTroughAllProperties("second", new List<Person> {person1, person2});
    }
```

The `Person` class:

```
    class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

And the `SearchStringTroughAllProperties` method:

```
    private static IEnumerable<Person> SearchStringTroughAllProperties(string stringToSearch,
        IEnumerable<Person> persons)
    {
        var properties =
            typeof (Person).GetProperties()
                .Where(x => x.CanRead && x.PropertyType == typeof (string))
                .Select(x => x.GetMethod)
                .Where(x => !x.IsStatic)
                .ToList();
        return persons.Where(person =>
            properties.Select(property => (string) property.Invoke(person, null) ?? string.Empty)
                .Any(propertyValueInInstance => propertyValueInInstance.Contains(stringToSearch)));
    }
```

Notice that:

- It searchs in properties, not in fields
- It only searchs on properties that can be read (have a get defined)
- It only searchs on properties of type string
- It only searchs on properties that aren't static members of the class

EDIT:

For searching the string coincidence in a `string` or `string[]` property, change `SearchStringTroughAllProperties` method to this (it gets longer!):

```
    static IEnumerable<Person> SearchStringTroughAllProperties(string stringToSearch, IEnumerable<Person> persons)
    {
        var properties =
            typeof (Person).GetProperties()
                .Where(x => x.CanRead && (x.PropertyType == typeof (string) || x.PropertyType == typeof(string[])))
                .Select(x => x.GetMethod)
                .Where(x => !x.IsStatic)
                .ToList();
        foreach (var person in persons)
        {
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                bool yieldReturned = false;
                switch (property.ReturnType.ToString())
                {
                    case "System.String":
                        var propertyValueStr = (string) property.Invoke(person, null) ?? string.Empty;
                        if (propertyValueStr.Contains(stringToSearch))
                        {
                            yield return person;
                            yieldReturned = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "System.String[]":
                        var propertyValueStrArr = (string[]) property.Invoke(person, null);
                        if (propertyValueStrArr != null && propertyValueStrArr.Any(x => x.Contains(stringToSearch)))
                        {
                            yield return person;
                            yieldReturned = true;
                        }
                        break;
                }
                if (yieldReturned)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks its working.only issue is that there are few properties having int as datatype and string[] as datatype.how to cater it?

Comment: how to search the searchstring in fields of different datatype like int,string,string[]

Comment: You want to also check values coincidences on those properties, or just omit them while values are checked?

Comment: Just saw your new comment. How will you convert an `int` to a `string`?

Comment: i have to serach a string in all columns of collection.One of the column having datatype string[].Now how to handle this?How can i search a specific string in collection of string in above code?

Comment: Check edit on answer. Note that by doing this a lot of LINQ code gets killed and code needed is longer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65459/discussion-between-f11-and-mishamosher).

Answer (score 0):

Even though work, it feels a bit dirty. I would consider maybe using reflection to get the properties of the class, and then dynamically search them.

The benefit would be: if you add a new property tomorrow, there's nothing else you need to change.

The disadvantage would be: probably not as performant since reflection is much slower than simply searching for things you know exist.

Having said that, i'm sure there are some other nifty advanced linq tricks that maybe others can point out.

- [Accessing Attributes by Using Reflection (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z919e8tw.aspx)

I thought I have some handy code but I don't. I wouldn't like to write it of the top of my head, because it probably won't compile (you need to get the syntax right). 
Have a look at the above link :)